# Upload Image Using Laravel Api with Auth Token Passport

Tags: laravel, authentication, postman, laravel-passport, laravel-api

I have uploaded an image from the postman with form-data using passport token. but it gave me an error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem. I have tried all solutions but it can't work.

Header with `Bearer Token` and Route with `auth:api` middleware.

Comment: you are passing content-type as form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded, but does it match with Accept header of your api ?

Comment: I didn't pass any header currently.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved by changing the PHP version. it's not working with the host when the PHP version is <= 7.3.15, its only works with IP. when updating the greater PHP version it's working in both(IP and host).